# iOS Framework Error duplicate Symbols with flag -all_load

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, linker, linker-errors

I have created a iOS Framework which is used to wrap some C++ code. This framework is working just fine as long as the app that includes my framework is not using:

```
Other Linker Flags: -all_load
```

If this flag is used I get a lot of Duplicate Symbol errors in the App that imports my framework:

```
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_LDRequest._ldProgressBlock in:
<pathToMyFramework>/ldhttpWrapper.framework/ldhttpWrapper(LDRequest-CF8E7CA9FA604178.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_LDRequest in:
<pathToMyFramework>/ldhttpWrapper.framework/ldhttpWrapper(LDRequest-CF8E7CA9FA604178.o)   
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_LDRequest in:
<pathToMyFramework>/ldhttpWrapper.framework/ldhttpWrapper(LDRequest-CF8E7CA9FA604178.o)
```

I get similar errors for all my objective-c classes.
My framework imports no external dependencies. So I ruled out that the importing application is having an issue with duplicated imports. I can also reproduce the error with an almost empty application.
So I would appreciate a idea what the issue could be here. Or some general information about "-all_load".

Answer (score 0):

Use Other Linker Flags: -force_load path_to_static_framework_executable_or_static_lib instead, for each of your libraries.